# Amortized analysis on Heap

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, amortized-analysis

When I ran to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103659/amortized-analysis-on-min-heap).

I read in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=fQVZy1zcpJkC&pg=SA5-PA1&lpg=SA5-PA1&dq=heap+insert+O%28log+n%29+delete+O%281%29+amortized&source=bl&ots=aFpoVgLkwO&sig=EbJaR0ksteHw9mATf4_eAczbRMc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cm0UVZDZHIPxapXBgeAC&ved=0CJcBEOgBMBQ#v=onepage&q=heap%20insert%20O%28log%20n%29%20delete%20O%281%29%20amortized&f=false) on the bottom of page 5-1 that *Binomial Queues*, *Fibonacci Heap* and *Skew Heap* have O(1) amortized cost for *insert* operations and O(log n) amortized cost of *delete* operations. Next the authors write that the *Pairing Heap* has O(1) amortized cost for insert operations and O(log n) amortized cost for delete operations.

on this [homework](http://[homewrk]:%20cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo09/assignments/assign5.pdf) the third (3) assignment and solution on this
[link](http://cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo09/assignments/assign5sol.pdf) without defining the type of heap wrote O(log n) for insert
and O(1) to delete.

on this homework [another](http://freiburg.de/teaching/ws14_15/algo1415/exercises/algo_exercise08_solution.pdf) the author says a *Binomial Heap* has O(log n) for insert operations and O(1) amortized cost for delete operations.

The question is, **which one is correct**? I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 4):

Since the heap has a nonnegative number of elements, it's always the case that #inserts ≥ #deletes if we start with an empty heap. With amortized time bounds, O(1) insert/O(log n) delete hence implies O(log n) insert/O(1) delete, by changing the accounting so that an insert prepays its corresponding delete (if extant). There's no contradiction there.

Comment: please explain more, it's so obvious for you, but not mine.

Comment: @jimmischel says in the post on above link  "I said that insert is close to O(1) and removal close to O(log n). I specifically stated that my analysis was limited to binary heaps. If you're using some other kind of heap (pairing heap, Fibonacci heap, etc.), then the behavior will be different. "

Comment: why  "O(1) insert/O(log n) delete hence implies O(log n) insert/O(1) delete" is hold?

Comment: @user4249446 Read the rest of the sentence? Another way to look at it is that we're changing potential functions from Phi(.) to Phi(.) + #elements \* Theta(log n).

Comment: yeah, is it possible to say simpler? in a way to understand me?

Comment: @user4249446 Insert increases the new potential function by an extra Theta(log n), so its amortized cost is now O(log n). Delete decreases the new potential function by an extra Theta(log n), where the big-Theta constant is enough to offset the previous amortized work, so the cost is free (O(1)).

Comment: my big question is  "O(1) insert/O(log n) delete hence implies O(log n) insert/O(1) delete" so the "O(log n) insert/O(1) delete hence implies O(1) insert/O(log n) delete" True? this is my misunderstanding point.

Comment: @user4249446 No, because there could be only insertions and nothing to charge the actual cost to.

Comment: my last questions is : 1) so we cannot say each of them implies insert O(log n) delete O(log n)?   2) it's not related which heap is used? Fibonacci or others?

Comment: Insert O(log n) and delete O(log n) is fine because everything that's O(1) is also O(log n). What matters to my argument is the amortization, not the choice of heap.

Comment: you means in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103659/amortized-analysis-on-min-heap   (a) (b) and (d) is true?  so strange me!!!!!

Comment: @user4249446 If those are amortized time bounds, then yes, given a theoretically best-in-class comparison-based heap.