# Why do both insertion and extraction into/from a std::priority_queue take logarithmic time?

Tags: c++, sorting, priority-queue

> A [[`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)] is a container adaptor that provides constant time lookup of the largest (by default) element, at the expense of **logarithmic insertion and extraction**.

Why is that? I think the sorting either happens on insertion or extraction.
For example, if the sorting happens on insertion and the internal container remains sorted, wouldn't the extraction be able to happen in constant time? The top element to be removed is know and so is the next smaller one.

However, both [`std::priority_queue::push`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push) and [`std::priority_queue::pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) mention in their complexity descriptions:

> ### Complexity
>
> Logarithmic number of comparisons

Why would **both** have to perform comparisons? With an internal container that stays sorted, extraction should be easy or vice versa, with sorting upon extraction, insertion should be easy.

I guess my assumption about when and how the sorting happens (or if there's any sorting happening at all) is just wrong. Could somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: You can find the the top element in constant time, but removing it requires reorganizing the storage somehow. How can you do that reorganization in constant time?

Comment: It's a heap, push needs to insert into the heap (comparing), extraction.. well.. it finds its element in O(1), but root must be the next largest element (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract).

Comment: @Barry If the storage is a sorted list, with the top element at the end, I don't understand what reorganisation has to go on.

Comment: @null Then insertion would be `n lg n` instead of `lg n`

Comment: @Caramiriel the quoted complexity statements are made besides what the internally used container requires for insertion and extraction. The complexity for inserting and removing the element that's specific for the used container is added on top of that. I do not understand how exactly the logarithmic complexity comes to be.

Comment: @Barry as mentioned in my earlier comment, it's apparently not possible to achieve such a complexity trade-off between insertion and extraction by picking a certain internal container, because the quoted documentation mentions the logarithmic complexity on top of whatever the container requires, so even a sorted list as described earlier would not allow for a constant time extraction even if one was willing to trade that for `n log n` complexity at insertion. I am not sure why there is a logarithmic complexity on both operations no matter what container is used. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @null Huh?? A sorted list would absolutely allow for constant time extraction. But it would make `n lg n` insertion, so it's less useful than a container that's `lg n` in both operations.

Comment: @Barry see, this is the reason I ask this question. Why would there be a logarithmic number of comparisons going on in such a case upon extraction as the documentation suggests?

Comment: @Barry a sorted linked list would have O(n) insertion complexity (which would still suck), not O(nlogn), and O(1) extraction.

Comment: @null you first said "if the storage is a sorted list", and then later said "the quoted complexity statements are made besides what the internally used container requires for insertion and extraction". The latter is accurate, making the former moot. The choice of container is up to the implementation, the standard only mandates the complexity requirement. That requirement states extraction can not be worse than O(logn). If you contrive an implementation that does it more efficient, so be it, but that is the threshold for standard compliance. So I honestly do not understand the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig "*The choice of container is up to the implementation*" according to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) this is not the case and the user can specify what kind of container is used as a template parameter.

Comment: @null You're correct, and I sit (been a long day) corrected. it is an adapter; not a container. You can provide any container you want so long as it supports random access (and fulfills the various other requirements). I meant to say the *adapter* can do whatever it wants so long as it abides by the standard for complexity. If an implementation can contrive a O(logn) insertion *and* better than O(logn) extraction, so be it. The point is, *neither* can be *worse* than O(logn). If your needs are different, the `std::priority_queue` adapter isn't right for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, it would `O(n)`. That's a silly error :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29107420/56778 for some relevant info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, if the sorting happens on insertion and the internal container remains sorted, wouldn't the extraction be able to happen in constant time?

Extract could happen in constant time, but insertion would become `O(n)`. You'd have to search for the place in the list to insert the new element and then shift all the other elements. `O(1)` extraction and `O(n)` insertion might be good for some use-cases, but not the problem that `priority_queue` is trying to solve.

If sorting, on the other hand, happened on extraction, then you'd have `O(n lg n)` extraction and `O(1)` insertion. Which, again, is good for some use-cases, but that's not what `priority_queue` does.

---

Rather than sorting elements, `std::priority_queue` stores its elements<sup>†</sup> in a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which by construction has `O(lg n)` insertion and extraction. The structure is a tree, and insertion/extraction simply maintain the tree invariant. For some problems (like, say, search), in cases where we need to insert and extract many nodes, having `O(lg n)` for both operations is far superior than `O(n)/O(1)`.

As an example, and stealing images from Wikipedia, inserting the element 15 into the heap would initially place it at position `x`:

[image: init]

then swap it with the `8` (because the sorted invariant is broken):

[image: 2nd step]

then finally swap it with the `11`:

[image: final step]

In array form, the initial heap would be stored as:

```
[11, 5, 8, 3, 4]
```

and we would end up at:

```
[15, 5, 11, 3, 4, 8]
```

Extraction is just the reverse operation - bubbling down instead of bubbling up. As you see, there's no explicit "sorting" going on. We're not even touching most of the elements most of the time.

---

<sup>†</sup>`std::priority_queue` is a container adapter, but the container you provide should be a random access container with `O(1)` complexities for indexing, `push_back`, `pop_back`, `front`, `back`, etc. So the choice of container (unless you make a bad one) does not affect the overall complexity of `priority_queue`'s operations.

Comment: Great, so my assumption about sorting was wrong. The algorithm operates on its own heap, which explains why the complexity of insertion and extraction is independent from the chosen internal container. What a revealing answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pop opration, remove the top element. There are several ways to implement a priority queue but in all of them, deleting the top is logarithmic. From wiki - [Priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Insertion with sorted list coast O(n log(n)).

Comment: _I'm_ aware of that. But that info is key to the misunderstanding that initiated this question, and therefore that information belongs in the answer.